# MTS MBlaze 3G USB Dongle in Mint 14 Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, usb, 3g

I recently installed Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon 64-bit along with Windows 7. I have a MTS Mblaze 3G USB dongle. This dongle has 2 modes i.e., 1X mode which gives less speed up—to 30 kbp/s and a broadband mode which gives more speed—up to or greater than 500 kbp/s.

In Win 7, this dongle works fine in broadband mode.

For using the 3g USB dongle I followed steps from this page:
http://telecomtalk.info/step-by-step-guide-configuring-usb-modem-ubuntu/101849/

It's good that Mint has inbuilt support for MTS dongles. But I am facing a problem as I cannot use my dongle in broadband mode in Mint. I have to start Windows, change the dongle mode to 1X mode and then start Mint. Then it connects to internet with 1X mode only giving less speed.

How can I connect the dongle in Broadband mode in Mint?

I also tried using `wvdial` but it gives an error as `/dev/modem` not found.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem.

First generate the wvdial.conf file using sudo wvdialconf. Change your user name, password and Phone number in /etc/wvdial.conf file.
Then run wvdial. Dongle will connect in broadband mode.